# How to prevent my cat from leaning down from balcony?

Tags: cats, behavior, safety

We live on 1st floor of a multi storey apartment. My cat's favorite time pass is to lean down from balcony and look at road. However it is extremely dangerous. If the street dogs get hold of her, they will tear her apart. Moreover a fall will severely injure her. Just day before yesterday she fell down and is still limping. However she refuses to listen to us. How to prevent her from leaning down from balcony. A point to be made is that often I take her out for a morning walk. So it is not that she never gets to go outside. However it is not possible to let her outside alone because of the street dogs. The dogs over here are cat killers.

Answer (score 2):

As you already pointed out: this situation is dangerous. You should secure the balcony by installing a net that will prevent your cat from falling or jumping off the balcony (a net appropriate for cats, holes not too large and the best would be a wire-supported net that cannot be bitten apart).